# How can I put this Binary Search to work?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search, helper

Is giving me an error in this code: c is a list or an array // k = is the number we want to check

```
def binary_search(c,k):
    low = 0
    high = len(c) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = floor((low + high) / 2)
        if c[mid] == k:
           return True
        elif c[mid] > k:
           high = mid - 1
        else:
           low = mid - 1
    return False
```

And this was the error: `File "C:/Users/JJ/OneDrive - ISCTE-IUL/EDA/Aula3.py", line 108, in binary_search
    mid = floor((low + high) / 2)
KeyboardInterrupt`

I don't why is this happening, so i need all the help I can get. Thanks for your time

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt just means that you quit the program with, e.g. Ctrl + C.  I'm guessing that the loop never ends because low keeps getting smaller.  Perhaps it should be increased?

Comment: @FiddleStix OMG, thanks!!!!!! It did help me a lot..

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your algorithm. Whenever you search for a number that does not exist in the list, your algorithm will keep running an infinite loop.

Comment: I had to switch in '-' for '+' on low. Thanks for the help @Ron Zhang